# What is the best way to run a function right before any other function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions, php-5.2

I am developing a permission based system which is going to be able to check permission for any functions in controller using codeigniter (HMVC). I want to be able to run a specific function to check permissions right before executing of that function. How is it possible?

Any kind of **help** or **idea** is appreciated

Comment: Tried using a [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)?

Comment: Hooks are not going to get executed on nested function calls ...

Comment: I am using a helper function like hasPermission("permission name") inside the function itself before doing any other thing. Is it not possible in your case?

Comment: Currently this is the only way I have found, but the problem is we have some plugin developers, So in this case we have to force them use this style of coding at the beginning of all their functions ...

Comment: You could execute the function from the controllers `__construct()`. That way it will automatically be executed in each subsequent function in that controller, or extension of that controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [post_controller_constructor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) hook.

Comment: This is not going to help. When I call nested functions, only hooks for last function is going to get executed. `Called after the final rendered page is sent to the browser, at the end of system execution after the finalized data is sent to the browser.`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your authentication library create a function that checks users roles and privileges
and on the controller of each function inside the constructor call your function.
I do it like this:

```
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->m_auth->notLogin();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('ajax_pagination');
    $this->load->library('dateconverter');
    $this->load->helper('check');
    $this->load->model('immovable/immovable_model');
    $this->lang->load('home',  $this->m_auth->get_language());
    $this->lang->load('personal',  $this->m_auth->get_language());
    $this->lang->load('global',  $this->m_auth->get_language());
    //this is the function which checks for roles of users
    $this->m_auth->check_asset_user();
}
```

for custom roles you can also create another function inside your authentication library
 and call it at the top of your functions and here is the code example:

```
public function get_data()
{
    if($this->m_auth->check_user()==2)
    {
        //do what you want
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('unauthorized');
    }
}
```